# How can we load multiple partial views on single view between specific time period?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have multiple partial view on my single view page. Partial views load dynamically. And I want partial views load 1 by 1. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you View, keep three Divs and assign the Url details in some attribute like below.

**Sample HTML**

```
<div id="Div1" attr-Url="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", 
                                                    new { area = "Area Name" })">
</div>

<div id="Div2" attr-Url="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", 
                                                    new { area = "Area Name" })">
</div>

<div id="Div3" attr-Url="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", 
                                                    new { area = "Area Name" })">
</div>
```

Now, you can use Success CallBack of Load Event.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = $('Div1').attr('attr-Url');
    $('Div1').load(url, function () {

        //Success callback
        url = $('Div2').attr('attr-Url2');
        $('Div2').load(url, function () {

            //Success callback
            url = $('Div3').attr('attr-Url3');
            $('Div3').load(url, function () {

                //Success callback
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

If you notice the above code. Once the first partial view is loaded successfully, Second Partial View starts to load and sequentially third.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: +1 for being less lazy than I was in my explanation, and actually writing out the call chain.

Answer (score 1):

This approach may be of use to you:

[Render Partial Views using JQuery in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487164/render-partial-views-using-jquery-in-mvc3)

It uses jquery and `.load()`, to call an action that renders your partial view as html and returns it to the javascript, that you'd later place wherever you desire.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to load them in a sequence, one after the other, you can use the complete callback of jquery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to chain one after the other.

If you want to have them load at specific times or intervals, you can use javascript's [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: Yah .. Its fine. But My question is different. I do not have issue with loading partial view with jquery or ajax or etc. I can load multiple partial views in my view page easily. I want that.. my partial views load within specific time.. 1 by 1.

Comment: Mmmm, you mean have one load after the other, or at specific times? Well, just use a javascript timer if you want at specific times, or use the "complete" callback parameter of jquery's .load(), to chain one after the other.