# Render multiple strongly typed partial views inside a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2012

I have this Index.cshtml class:

```
@model ProOptInteractive.ViewModels.InvoicePageViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div>@Html.Partial("ListServices", Model.Services)</div>
<div>@Html.Partial("ListProducts", Model.Products)</div>
<div>@Html.Partial("Invoice", Model.InvoiceViewModel)</div>
```

And this is my InvoicePageViewModel:

```
namespace ProOptInteractive.ViewModels
{
    public class InvoicePageViewModel
    {
        public InvoiceViewModel InvoiceViewModel { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The issue is that whenever I load this view, I get an error saying that I have passed the wrong model to the dictionary, and it doesn't specify which one of the partial views is causing the problem. Each partial has a different model type, one IEnumerable called Product, another IEnumerable called Service, and the Invoice partial view having a viewmodel called InvoiceViewModel.

Can anybody explain how to go about making this work? I'm a bit noob at Razor and MVC by the way.

**UPDATE**

I get this error message:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ProOptInteractive.ViewModels.InvoiceViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ProOptInteractive.ViewModels.InvoicePageViewModel'.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you post error message?

Comment: **[Try loading the partial view sequentially](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15793019/2007801)**

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ProOptInteractive.ViewModels.InvoiceViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ProOptInteractive.Models.Service]'.

Comment: Try loading the Partial View Asynchronously. If you get error you can add more parameters to check **[which Partial View is causing the error as mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16245682/2007801)**

Comment: Can you post your partialView code, maybe you didn't reference right view model there?

Comment: What are you passing from action method? ideally it should be InvoicePageViewModel. Also check the model specified  in Invoice.cshtml that should InvoiceViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the error. It was lying in the controller method. When I called the Index view (which corresponds to the ActionResult Index method) I was returning the viewmodel InvoiceViewModel to the Index page, even though it was strongly typed to InvoicePageViewModel. I changed it to this, which works:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var invoice = InvoiceLogic.GetInvoice(this.HttpContext);

    // Set up our ViewModel
    var pageViewModel = new InvoicePageViewModel
    {
        Products = proent.Products.ToList(),
        Services = proent.Services.ToList(),
        InvoiceViewModel = new InvoiceViewModel
    {

        InvoiceItems = invoice.GetInvoiceItems(),
        Clients = proent.Clients.ToList(),
        InvoiceTotal = invoice.GetTotal()
    }
};
    // Return the view
    return View(pageViewModel);
}
```

Thanks to everyone for all the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you have set your `Invoice` partial view to have a model of type `InvoicePageViewModel`, yet you are passing it a model of type `InvoiceViewModel`.

Either update your `InvoiceViewModel` property to be of type `InvoicePageViewModel`, or change the `Invoice` view to use a model of type `InvoiceViewModel`.

Comment: Yes, almost certainly a type-o in the model declaration for the Invoice partial.

Comment: It's exactly like this now, Invoice.cshtml has a model declaration called InvoiceViewModel. I've checked. Hence my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Error is in line `<div>@Html.Partial("Invoice", Model.InvoiceViewModel)</div>`

Your view `Invoice` is accepting model of type 
`InvoicePageViewModel` and you are passing `InvoiceViewModel`

Change your code to `<div>@Html.Partial("Invoice", Model)</div>`

or modify your `Invoice` view to accept `InvoiceViewModel` as

`@model ProOptInteractive.ViewModels.InvoiceViewModel`

Answer (score 2):

`Invoice.cshtml` likely starts with:

```
@model ProOptInteractive.ViewModels.InvoicePageViewModel
```

replace it with:

```
@model ProOptInteractive.ViewModels.InvoiceViewModel
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass model to your partial view like this:

```
@Html.Partial("Invoice", Model.InvoiceViewModel)
```

or something similar.

Model for main view:

```
class InvoicePageViewModel {
...
    public InvoiceViewModel InvoiceViewModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
...
}
```

Then update your partial view to accept view model like this:

```
@model InvoiceViewModel

...
```

Comment: that would require i instantiate three different models in one view, which is impossible

Comment: You can create one Model and put all three partial models in it and pass it like Model.Product or something else

Comment: I updated the question, I think I was already doing something similar to what you suggested.